# ASP.Net Web Api in separate web app or not?

Tags: jquery, ajax, architecture, authorization, asp.net-web-api

I want to use an ASP.Net Web API to access using JQuery AJAX. The Web API should have authorized and unauthorized methods. When integrating the Web API inside the existing MVC project, it works out of box.

But I'd like to have a separate project for my Web API, so I can use it on more applications. However when I'm authorized on the website and do a JQuery call to the Web API (on a virtual directory inside the IIS webapp) it does not authenticate. But it sends the forms authentication headers in the request.

Is it a good idea to have a separate Web API project for multiple web applications, or is it maybe smarter to integrate some Web API controllers in every web application specific?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MVC and Web API are really the same stack. It is unfortunate that in the current implementation they live in parallel (though adjacent) worlds.

I personally prefer to have a single site providing both data (Web API) and rendered views (MVC, etc) since a lot of logic are shared.

The authentication is a cross-cutting concern so it could be designed to allow forms, OAuth, basic, etc.

Comment: I actually ended up using this technique. I've created a WebAPI inside the MVC project. Then the authentication will be done automatically.

Comment: @RodyvanSambeek yup. That is what I would do.